# Optimization Understanding

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I would like to know the appropriate steps in maximizing or minimizing certain things in problems such as the following:

Maximize $Q = xy^2$, where $x$ & $y$ are positive such that $x + y^2 = 4$.

I want to know the steps associated with optimization in general.

Comment: Optimization in general is hard -- convex problems (or techniques which work on them, like gradient descent/stochastic gradient descent/extensions) are basically the workhorse for many types of continuous optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, establish a relationship between the variables.

Here, we have $x=4-y^2$.

Next, optimize! We have to optimize $Q=4y^2-y^4$.

We find $dQ = 8y-4y^3=4y(2-y^2)$.

We know $y$ is positive, so $y=\sqrt{2}$ (rule out other zeros, which are $0$, and $-\sqrt{2}$). Therefore, $x=2$.

And plugging into $Q=xy^2$ gives us $\boxed{Q=4}$ :D

Comment: plugging $x=2$ into $Q=xy^2$ gives me $Q=2y^2$?

Comment: plug both x and y into Q

Answer (score 1):

$ x= 4-y^2$

$Q = (4-y^2)y^2$

Set $dQ/dy = 0 $  find positive y and find x later.

Comment: Oh, okay. Solve for an x or y, then plug it in and differentiate.

Comment: Find x and y and plug in the values of x and y in Q and that will be your Maximum

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM $xy^2\leq\frac{(x+y^2)^2}{4}=4$.

The equality occurs for $x=y^2=2$, which gives the answer: $4$.